# Cocos2d: Controller calling method of a CCNode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My GameController.m calls a method of CCNode class.  It seems to call it as I can see NSLog but the method is not either operate or not result in view.  In other words, screen does not change when calling the method from GameController.  (method operates itself in its own class)

How should I change my code to fix it?

Summary:
GameController -> calls -> GoalPost.GoalKeeper.method.

Code:
GameController.m, GoalPost.m and GoalKeeper.m

GameController.m

```
#import "GameController.h"
#import "cocos2d-ui.h"
#import "GoalPost.h"
#import "Ball.h"
#import "Field.h"

@interface GameController()
@property Field* field;
//@property Ball* ball;
@property GoalPost* post;
@end

@implementation GameController

- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.field = [Field node];
//        self.ball = [Ball node];
    self.post = [GoalPost node];

}
return self;
}

//control computer.
-(void)kickerTurn{
NSLog(@"Player kick");
//random location generation
//call keeper.
int randomKeeperX = arc4random() % (int)self.post.contentSize.width;
int randomKeeperY = arc4random() % (int)self.post.contentSize.height;
CGPoint keeperLoc = ccp(randomKeeperX, randomKeeperY);

[self.post.keeper keeperLocation:keeperLoc];
}

@end
```

GoalPost.h

```
#import "GoalKeeper.h"
@interface GoalPost : CCNodeColor {   }
@property GoalKeeper* keeper;
@end
```

GoalPost.m

```
#import "GoalPost.h"
#import "GoalKeeper.h"
@interface GoalPost ()
@property NSArray* post;
@end

@implementation GoalPost
- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super initWithColor:[CCColor lightGrayColor]];
if (self) {
    ....
        [self addChild:aPost];
    }

    //Call goal keeper and add.
    //for touch to run goal keeper.
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
    self.keeper = [GoalKeeper node];

    //Put it in front of goal post.
    self.keeper.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2, 0);
    [self addChild:self.keeper];

}
return self;
}

-(void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];
NSLog(@"Goal touched: %f %f", touchLoc.x, touchLoc.y);
//Goal keeper call
[self.keeper keeperLocation:touchLoc];

}

@end
```

Finally, GoalKeeper.m

.h
    #import "cocos2d.h"

```
@interface GoalKeeper : CCNodeColor { }
-(void)keeperLocation:(CGPoint)location;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "GoalKeeper.h"
@interface GoalKeeper()
@property CGPoint touchLoc;
@end

@implementation GoalKeeper

- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super initWithColor:[CCColor blueColor]];
if (self) {
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(30, 70)];

}
return self;
}

-(void)keeperLocation:(CGPoint)location {

CGPoint offset = ccpSub(location, self.position);
int targetX = self.position.x + offset.x;
int targetY = self.position.y + offset.y;
CGPoint targetPosition = ccp(targetX, targetY);

CCActionMoveBy *actionMoveBy = [CCActionMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.5f position:offset];
[self runAction:actionMoveBy];
}

@end
```

Comment: how often is keeperLocation called? If it happens every frame it won't work because actions need time to take effect, plus if a move action is already running they'll interfere with each other

Comment: @LearnCocos2D It should happen once. Just like when AppDelegate start a scene where the scene calls GameController.  I will add more control to call keeperLocation when needed.